# python - remove a dictionary from a list if dictionary key equals a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to know how to remove a specific dict from this list if user status equals "offline" and order type equals "buy" (iterating over it with for loop and modifying the list while iterating produces an exception because of the list pointer)

```
mylist = [
           {
             "user": {"status": "offline"}, 
             "order_type": "buy"
           },
           {
             "user": {"status": "online"},
             "order_type": "sell"
           }
         ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-create the list without undesired elements:

```
mylist = [key_values for key_values in mylist if key_values['user']['status'] != 'offline']
```

(*) do not name your variables using reserved keywords.

Comment: produces an exception, KeyError: 'status' and "list" variable name was just an example

Comment: whoops, there are nested dicts. fixed it. Whatever the excuse, don't shadow keywords.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = [
         {
           "user": {"status": "offline"}, 
           "order_type": "buy"
         },
         {  "user": {"status": "online"},
            "order_type": "sell"
         }
       ]

for _ in seq:
    print _
    if _['user']['status'] == 'offline':
        seq.remove(_)

print seq
```

In case if you're looking for in place removal.

**output:**
`[{'user': {'status': 'online'}, 'order_type': 'sell'}]`

Comment: that doesn't work because its a big list and you can't modify while iterating because of the pointer